# SQL Server XML Querying with specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a XML as below in one of the table column of type xml

```
<fields>
  <field>
    <name>SourceFileName</name>
    <value>ABCD</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>Template</name>
    <value>XYZ</value>
  </field>
</fields>
```

I need to query the XML to get the value for a specific text in **field/name** node

i used the below SQL but it doesn't return  any data for the second one

```
SELECT *
FROM   xmltable
WHERE  XMLText.value('(/fields/field/name)**[1]**' ,'varchar(max)') LIKE 
       'Template'

SELECT *
FROM   xmltable
WHERE  XMLText.value('(/fields/field/name)**[1]**' ,'varchar(max)') LIKE 
       'SourceFileName'
```

whereas the below returns data

```
SELECT *
FROM   xmltable
WHERE  XMLText.value('(/fields/field/name)**[2]**' ,'varchar(max)') LIKE 
       'Template'
```

Can somebody help, how do i write a generic query to return data based on the name passed?

Comment: How does this work for Update - Update @T Set XMLText.modify('replace value of (value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@NewVal")') FROM @T CROSS APPLY XMLText.nodes('/fields/field') AS XT(XC) where XC.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') like 'Template'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle **multiple** XML elements, you need to use the `.nodes()` XQuery function.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    Name = XC.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    [Value] = XC.value('(value)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
FROM
    dbo.XmlTable
CROSS APPLY
    XmlText.nodes('/fields/field') AS XT(XC)
```

The `.nodes()` call will create a "pseudo" table `XT` with a single column `XC` that contains the XML fragment that is matched by that XPath expression - in your case, you get two rows, each representing one of the `<field>` elements.

You can now "reach into" those XML fragments and extract the data you need using the `.value()` calls - and you get the name and value for **both** `<field>` elements this way:

[image]

Comment: Thank you marc. It worked like a charm. Kudos for your quick response.

Comment: Another quick question. How does this work for Update     -                   Update @T Set  
 XMLText.modify('replace value of (value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@NewVal")')
FROM
    @T
CROSS APPLY
    XMLText.nodes('/fields/field') AS XT(XC)
where  XC.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') like 'Template'